# Detect when a field of a colletion has changed with .next() with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Supposing I've some documents with a field `'State'`, I need to detect it changes in the next documents. For that, I want to compare current cursor with `next()`:

```
cursor.forEach(
        function(thisCursor){
            print('Current: '+thisCursor.State);
            print('Next: '+cursor.next().State);
        }
)
```

But output is like this:

```
Current: Florida
Next: Florida
Current: New Mexico
Next: New Mexico
```

So clearly `.next()` is not working at all. Any ideas about why this occurs?

Thanks

Comment: What platform / programming language are you using?

Comment: Just mongoDB javascript command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use `forEach` to iterate through the collection, you'll end up skipping every other index.

A cursor is just a position in the result set. `forEach` normally moves the current to the next item, but by calling `next` manually on the cursor instance, you'll be skipping through the collection, maybe unintentionally.

```
> db.states.remove()
> db.states.insert({name: "alabama"})
> db.states.insert({name: "alaska"})
> db.states.insert({name: "arkansas"})
> db.states.insert({name: "wisconsin"})
> db.states.insert({name: "west virginia"})
```

Then, initialize the cursor:

```
> var cursor=db.states.find();
```

If I use `forEach` and `next`:

```
> cursor.forEach(function(item){ 
     print("name: " + item.name); 
     print("next name: " + cursor.next().name); })
```

It results in:

```
name: alabama
next name: alaska
name: arkansas
next name: wisconsin
name: west virginia
Sun Aug 25 15:04:12.197 error hasNext: false at src/mongo/shell/query.js:124
```

As you can see, the cursor moves through the collection and then, because `hasNext` wasn't used, it steps one **beyond** the length of the collection.

You'll need to change your logic to actually read the "next" document and not have it affect the following `forEach` loop iteration.

While I don't understand the nature of your data, you might be able to do something like this:

```
> var doc=cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : null;
> while(doc) { 
        var currentDoc=cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : null; 
        if(currentDoc && currentDoc.name === doc.name) { 
            print("matched: " + currentDoc.name); 
        }  
        doc = currentDoc;             
   }
```

It fetches one document, then grabs the next document if there is one and compares it to the first one. Then, repeats by comparing previous document to the current document. Loop until there are no more documents.

If your logic gets more complex, I'd strongly suggest you try using Node.JS and the native MongoDB driver.

Also, if you've got more than 20 results, you may need to set the batch size to a larger number. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#executing-queries).